# laptop shows no login screen Ubuntu Mate

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, login, mate

I have Ubuntu Mate 15.10 and Windows 10 installed on my laptop as a dual boot.
For some reason, after I select Ubuntu in GRUB, the login screen (greeter?) is not showing. The screen is completely black but i can see that the back light is on.

Strange part is that when i just type my password and press enter, it will take me to the desktop environment! and when i lock my screen, i can see the login screen.
Another thing that worked was, when i boot into recovery mode and then choose resume, this also works.

I already did a boot-repair but this didn't work.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: That sounds a bit like your laptop "thinks", you have a second screen... Can you try connecting an external screen and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed.
Fixed by restoring grub boot menu and update-grub.
Now the login screen works

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)